# How to dynamically change element margin-top dependent on body height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, height

I have a container within my body and I need to set this element to centered vertical alignment. I need to do this also dependent on body height, and change it dynamically.

I tried with something like the below code, but it doesn't work perfectly and most importantly not dynamic. Note: I can't do this with css.

```
var ah = $('body').height();
var ph = $('#main_container').parent().height();
var mh = Math.ceil((ph-ah) / 2);
$('#main_container').css('margin-top', mh);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject CSS using JQuery:

```
$('#main_container').css("position", "absolute");
$('#main_container').css("margin-top", "auto");
$('#main_container').css("margin-bottom", "auto");
$('#main_container').css("top", 0);
$('#main_container').css("bottom", 0);
```

If you also want to horizontally center it, you can delete the `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` lines, and add:

```
$('#main_container').css("margin", "auto");
$('#main_container').css("left", 0);
$('#main_container').css("right", 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Bind it to the `resize` event:

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    var $container = $('#main_container');
    var height = Math.ceil(($container.parent().height() - $('body').height()) / 2);

    $container.css({marginTop: height});
}).trigger('resize');
```

It won't be as smooth as CSS, but it will work. Why can't you do it with CSS?

Comment: i don't know why but it does't work, i have some other hidden elements and if i do this with css it will be crusch them...